# Left join two pandas dataframes on Id when time in one dataframe is between two dates in the other

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have two dataframe:

```py
#trans
orgid  transdate
------+---------
1         2021-01-30
1         2021-02-05
2         2020-05-12
3         2020-06-02
3         2010-05-12
```

```py
#licenses

id  start        end
---+------------+----------
1    2020-01-02   2021-02-02
1    2018-03-17   2018-04-03
2    2020-04-01   2021-05-01
3    2020-06-01   2021-07-01
```

I want a new column in `trans` called `was_licensed` if `transdate` is between any pair of `start` and `end` (for the same `id`) e.g

```py
#trans
orgid  transdate      was_licensed
------+-------------+-------------
1         2021-01-30       True    #2021-01-30 is between [2020-01-02   2021-02-02]
1         2021-02-05       False   # No interval where 2021-02-05 is between for "id"=1
2         2020-05-12       False
3         2020-06-02       True
3         2010-05-12       False
```

I have tried `pandasql` like

```py
cond_join= '''
    select data_left.* data_right.*,
    from trans as data_left
    left join license as data_right 
    on
        data_left.Id=data_right.Id
         AND
        data_left.transdate >= data_right.[start]
        AND
        data_left.transdate<= data_right.[end]
'''
```

but that yields more rows that `trans` i.e it does not seem like a left join (`licenses` has no duplicates), and I cannot figure out where those additional columns comes from.

Furthermore I have tried `pyjanitor`

````py
data_end = trans.conditional_join(licenses,("transdate","start",">="),("transdate","end","<="),("id","id","=="),how="left")```
with the same issue as `pandasql`.
````

I have around ~9 mio rows thus looping over each of them is not very sufficient

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
df1['transdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['transdate'])
df2['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['start'])
df2['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['end'])

out = (
    df1.merge(df2, left_on='orgid', right_on='id', how='left')
       .assign(was_licenced=lambda x: x['transdate'].between(x['start'], x['end']))
       .sort_values('was_licenced', ascending=False)
       .drop_duplicates(['orgid', 'transdate']).sort_index()
       .drop(columns=['start', 'end'])
)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   orgid  transdate  id  was_licenced
0      1 2021-01-30   1          True
2      1 2021-02-05   1         False
4      2 2020-05-12   2          True
5      3 2020-06-02   3          True
6      3 2010-05-12   3         False
```

Comment: If my answer is right, I can give you more explanation about `.sort_values('was_licenced', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['orgid', 'transdate']).sort_index()`

Comment: it seems like it drops ~50% of the columns i.e `out.shape[0]:= df1.shape[0]*0.5`